# No such file or directory - Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to convert an exsiting jsp file to pdf.

For that I am using itext library.

My Servlet Class for conversion

```
package com.kunal.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.activation.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper;





/**
 * Servlet implementation class CartCheckout
 */
@WebServlet("/CartCheckout")
public class CartCheckout extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public CartCheckout() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        try
        {
        // step 1
        Document document = new Document();
        // step 2
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("pdf.pdf"));
        // step 3
        document.open();
        // step 4
        XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document,
                new FileInputStream("WebContent/Test1.jsp")); 
        //step 5
         document.close();

        System.out.println( "PDF Created!" );
    }
        catch(DocumentException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


}
}
```

My `Test1.jsp` file is in `WebContent->Test1.jsp`

When I run the servlet it gives a FileNotFoundException

Stacktrace

```
Sep 04, 2014 1:10:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
Sep 04, 2014 1:10:33 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Agro' did not find a matching property.
Sep 04, 2014 1:10:33 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Sep 04, 2014 1:10:33 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Sep 04, 2014 1:10:33 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Sep 04, 2014 1:10:33 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Sep 04, 2014 1:10:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 662 ms
Sep 04, 2014 1:10:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Sep 04, 2014 1:10:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.9
Sep 04, 2014 1:10:35 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Sep 04, 2014 1:10:35 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Sep 04, 2014 1:10:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1626 ms
Sep 04, 2014 1:10:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Cart_Checkout] in context with path [/Agro] threw exception
java.io.FileNotFoundException: WebContent/Test1.jsp (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
    at com.kunal.servlet.CartCheckout.doPost(CartCheckout.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Obviously, the file `WebContent/Test1.jsp` does not exist...

Comment: It is there in my project. Inside the WebContent folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are running the web application, in the server webcontent folder will not be available . so better to create one directory in webcontent directory with the name jsp (or some other name) and use in servlet as **/jsp/Test.jsp** , it will work.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using `FileInputStream("WebContent/Test1.jsp")` that does it mean that the file must exists.

If you want to dump all the **JSP** content into a **PDF** that could not exists, you should use `OutputStreamWriter`

[Oracle OutputStreamWrite Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html)